# Get tuple of the first and last days of the last N months

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to get a tuple of `date` (or `datetime`) objects over the last `N` months.

My thought was to use the `dateutil` package with something like this:

```
def last_n_months(n=12, ending=None):
    """Return a list of tuples of the first/last day of the month
    for the last N months    
    """
    from datetime import date
    from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MONTHLY
    from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

    if not ending:
        ending = date.today()

    # set the ending date to the last day of the month
    ending = ending + relativedelta(months=+1, days=-ending.day)

    # starting is the first day of the month N months ago
    starting = ending - relativedelta(months=n, day=1)

    months = list(rrule(MONTHLY, bymonthday=(1, -1), dtstart=starting,
                        until=ending))

    # we return pairs of dates like this: (1st day of month, last day of month)
    months = zip(months[::2], months[1::2])

    return months
```

Example usage:

```
    >>> from datetime import date, timedelta

    # get last two months as a degenerate example
    >>> l2n = last_n_months(2, ending=date(2012, 01, 01))
    >>> map(lambda x: [x[0].year, x[0].month, x[0].day], l2n)
    [[2011, 11, 1], [2011, 12, 1], [2012, 1, 1]]
    >>> map(lambda x: [x[1].year, x[1].month, x[1].day], l2n)
    [[2011, 11, 30], [2011, 12, 31], [2012, 1, 31]]

    >>> l24n = last_n_months(24, ending=date(2012,03,16))
    >>> len(l24n) # inclusive of current month
    25

    # every tuple starts with the first day of the month
    >>> all(x[0].day == 1 for x in l24n)
    True

    # every tuple ends with the last day of the month
    >>> all((x[1] +timedelta(days=1)).month != x[1].month for x in l24n)
    True

    # every tuple is the same month
    >>> all(x[0].month == x[1].month for x in l24n)
    True
```

I am posting it here to see if anyone has a better solution than this (and perhaps see if this yields some off-by-one sort of error that I haven't thought of).

Is there a simpler or faster solution than this?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you can probably adapt the itermonthdates() function from the calendar module in the python standard library:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html
No?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def last_n_months(n=12, ending=None):
    """Return a list of tuples of the first/last day of the month
    for the last N months    
    """
    from datetime import date
    from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MONTHLY
    from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
```

It is better to import outside of the function. Typically imports go at the top of the file.

```
    if not ending:
```

You should check for none like: `if ending is not None:` just to be explicit about what you are checking for.

```
        ending = date.today()

    # set the ending date to the last day of the month
    ending = ending + relativedelta(months=+1, days=-ending.day)
```

Modifying `ending` rubs me the wrong way.

```
    # starting is the first day of the month N months ago
    starting = ending - relativedelta(months=n, day=1)

    months = list(rrule(MONTHLY, bymonthday=(1, -1), dtstart=starting,
                        until=ending))

    # we return pairs of dates like this: (1st day of month, last day of month)
    months = zip(months[::2], months[1::2])

    return months
```

You can combine these two lines

Comment: Thanks Winston, much appreciated. Quick question with respect to the imports, is the preference to import outside the function a preference or functional? From a PEP? Always preferable where there are no circular dependencies? Or is there a concern about cluttering the namespace? Just curious - I'd be very grateful if anyone were to post a link to a discussion.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt, PEP 8 says to put all imports at the top. See here for some discussion of it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477096/python-import-coding-style

Comment: Thanks for the discussion thread. A quote I thought interesting in one of the upvoted answers "As you can see, it can be more efficient to import the module in the function"

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt, yes but that only applies if you are calling the function a lot. In your case it doesn't, because you only use any of those imports a few times.